# CloudKit Offline Sync

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I'm working on a CloudKit app. Can `fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs` be used to handle offline changes?

What's the use of `longLivedOperationWasPersistedBlock`?

I see that `longLivedOperationWasPersistedBlock` gets called even when the app is offline

Answer (score 4):

In order to work with CloudKit you must be online. Being offline returns a CKError detailed and Internet Connecction error.

fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs only returns the operations IDs that are running or had finished in a short period of time.

If you goes offline you need some kind of local persitance engine. It could be Core Data, KeyedArchive or something like that.